# Random float sleep in bash script?

Tags: bash, random, sleep

I need randomized pauses in my script between two numbers smaller than 1 second in my script. The following used to work:

```
#! /bin/bash
sleep $(python -c "import random;print random.uniform(.2,.8)")
```

But suddenly it doesn't anymore. Is there any other way to do it?

I'm on Linux Mint 20, if that matters.

Comment: define doesn't work and have you changed systems?

Comment: The script simply ignores that line and runs everything else. I haven't changed my system, I only updated it using the Update Manager. I'm on Linux Mint 20 btw, gonna edit the question.

Comment: ... in particular, see [Essential syntax differences - print](https://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#print) if the system's default python changed from python2 to python3

Comment: Do I check system's default by trying to print something in the terminal? I get 
$ print 'Hello'
Error: no such file "Hello"
and 
$ print('Hello')
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'Hello''

Comment: Try `python --version`

Comment: I get `bash: python: command not found`. if I do `python3 --version` it says `Python 3.8.10`

Comment: That means your `$(python ...` won't work. Use `$(python3 ...`

Comment: In Python3 `print` is a function, so you'll need to change the syntax slightly by enclosing the item to print in parentheses: `python3 -c "import random;print(random.uniform(.2,.8))"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your python-based solution is failing because your OS has deprecated `python2` in favor of `python3`. As part of that process, `/usr/bin/python` no longer points to *either* by default.

In python3 `print` is a function and needs parentheses around its arguments<sup>1</sup>. So you could use:

```
sleep $(python3 -c "import random;print(random.uniform(.2,.8))")
```

However for the simple case of a sleep value between 200ms and 800ms you could likely get away with generating an *integer* between 200 and 600 (which you can do in bash using the built-in `RANDOM` variable, plus some modulo arithmetic), and prepending `0.`:

```
sleep 0.$((200 + RANDOM%600))
```

---

1. see for example [python-future: Essential syntax differences - print](https://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#print)

Comment: Oh! I tried changing `python` to `python3` but I didn't notice I had to add the parentheses after `print`, even though you linked me to those syntax differences. It works now, thanks! I tried the solution using only RANDOM as well, but it didn't work.